# How should I store localized Strings in an iOS project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nsstring, nslocalizedstring

I’m developing an iOS application. One of my tasks is localization. For this reason, I’ve taken all strings and put them each in a `NSLocalizedString(key,comment)`, and everything’s been OK.

But my new solution is to create a Singleton class, which stores every `String` that I use in the project. With this I have one small, but tricky problem: naming. Do I need to create some dictionaries for every class (view) that needs localized strings? Or should I use prefixes for this, or functions that return objects with good, understandable property names?

P.S: i don't want to invent new wheel. I want to create STORAGE of localized strings, that will be used in project. So, my target is to make singleton:

`[[[StringStorage sharedInstance] getStringsForClass:self] objectForKey:@"title"];`

or something like this:

`[StringStorage sharedInstance].stringTitleForMainView`

Comment: You're trying to create your own localisation technique? Why not just use the one that Apple provides and has a team of people working on to make it easy to use and reliable?

Comment: If you're going to base your localization on the default language setting on the phone, just use the built in features that Apple provides.  If you want something else -- like the ability to change the language in your app, regardless of what the phone's default language is -- then you may need to roll your own.  I can provide samples if you wish.

Comment: May I ask if you're trying to do that on iOS6? Or also iOS5?

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish adding that singleton class?

Comment: please, read my question first. I want to create STORAGE, not LOCALIZATIONS OR SOMETHING SIMILAR. And i don't know, is it good or not? It really helps me to create new strings and view, that should have localization (and strings )

Comment: I think the question is what problem are you trying to solve by storing all strings in a singleton? It is helpful to know the trouble you are having before recommending any solution.

Comment: A Singleton is never the solution for anything!

Comment: @JefferyThomas i think, that Sven answer for my question

Answer (score 1):

You really should stick with `NSLocalizedString` and `NSLocalizedStringFromTable`. You also can use the `NSBundle` method `localizedStringForKey:value:table:`.

But if you take any other route you are reinventing the wheel, and you lose the ability to use the `genstrings` command line tool to extract all your strings from the source code.

Comment: if i have several view controllers, i need several files (tables.strings) for each controller?